# JsonAlias as default openapi dto property name

Tags: java, rest, jackson, swagger, openapi

I have a dto used as request body in a rest service:

```
@Data
public class MyClass {
    @JsonAlias("myAlias")
    private String myProperty;
}
```

When we produce our openapi/swagger yaml the property name is "myProperty"

Is it possible to automatically force the alias inside the openapi/swagger produced?
(annotation? during yaml creation? anything else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization always uses the primary name - in this case, `myProperty`. In order to change the outputted name, you'd need to change the name of `myProperty`. The [JsonAlias](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) annotation only affects deserialization - the alias is an alternate name.